# How can I style my contact form 7 and then use the shortcode in slider revolution

Tags: css, wordpress

I have a contact form 7 form that I want to add to my slider revolution header using the shortcode. How would I be able to style my form with CSS so that it changes when I use the shortcode for it? Are there any other options for me to use custom CSS forms with shortcode?

What I have tried doing is customizing the form in elementor but those styles do not change the form when the shortcode is used, it only updates on the elementor page.

Comment: It will be nice if you post some of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the inspect element of the browser, example on Chrome, right click an element you want to check then click inspect element then try to find for a unique class name for each field or you may try to find the "form" tag and get it's class name usually it looks something like this [cf7 inspect element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z0OMU.png)

here's an example css lines to change the style of all the input fields and the button

form.wpcf7-form input {border:1px solid #ff0000;}
form.wpcf7-form input[type="submit"] {background: #ff0000;}